# Spring Rest Template Http client error exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

RestTemplate Works fine with internal url but fails with public url.

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    setTimeout(restTemplate , 40000 , 40000);
    return restTemplate;
}

private void setTimeout(RestTemplate restTemplate, int readTimeOut , int connectionTimeOut) {
    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory());
    SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory rf = (SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory) restTemplate.getRequestFactory();
    rf.setReadTimeout(readTimeOut);
    rf.setConnectTimeout(connectionTimeOut);
}
```

Is there any way to fix this issue ?

it throws Httpclientexception by restteamplate when accessing public url.

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request
17:24:46,913 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:79) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
17:24:46,913 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:122) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
17:24:46,913 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
17:24:46,913 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
17:24:46,914 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:777) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
17:24:46,914 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:735) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
17:24:46,914 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:669) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
17:24:46,914 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:578) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
17:24:46,914 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at com.epic.edbs.ib.serviceclient.RestClient.processRestCall(RestClient.java:46) ~[IB-1.00.jar:?]
17:24:46,915 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at com.epic.edbs.ib.serviceclient.EswitchClient.processRequest(EswitchClient.java:92) ~[IB-1.00.jar:?]
17:24:46,915 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at com.epic.edbs.ib_rest.servicekeyexchange.impl.ServiceKeyExchangeImpl.getUserKey(ServiceKeyExchangeImpl.java:79) ~[classes:?]
17:24:46,915 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at com.epic.edbs.ib_rest.servicekeyexchange.impl.ServiceKeyExchangeImpl.getUserExchangeKey(ServiceKeyExchangeImpl.java:49) ~[classes:?]
17:24:46,916 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at com.epic.edbs.ib_rest.servicekeyexchange.impl.ServiceKeyExchangeImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$df1e3370.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes:?]
17:24:46,916 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
17:24:46,916 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
17:24:46,916 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
17:24:46,916 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:55) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
17:24:46,916 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
17:24:46,916 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:56) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
17:24:46,917 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
17:24:46,917 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:55) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
17:24:46,919 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175) ~[spring-aop-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
```

Comment: As the server complains about the request, you might want to add it, how you convert it to a `byte[]` and the `setHeaders` method to the question.

Comment: String requestHexString = ISOUtil.hexString(request); convert byte[] to string and set it to request body

Comment: Please edit you question and add the actual content you are trying to send.

Comment: actually resttemplate works with internal url but fails with public url .That is the my concern.

Comment: The *server* you are calling is rejecting the request. Without knowing the service yoiu are calling and the request you are sending then I am not sure how anyone can help. If you are in control of the service being called then first thing to do would be fix it to return a meaningful error response.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer using below url.

I have missed `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` annotation in request bean.

https://www.oipapio.com/question-9416560

Thank you very much for your great contribution.